# Flutter async executing on main thread

Tags: dart, async-await

I have a `CameraPreview` that fills the whole screen, with a `FloatingActionButton` at the bottom to take a picture.

On the `onPress` method of the button, I'm making a **network call for which I do not care (yet) about the result**. So I would like everything made inside that method to be done asynchronously, so it does not block my main thread.

That means (if I get it right) that I sould not use the `await` keyword.

This is the code in my `onPressed`

```
// Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved
await controller.takePicture(path);
print("Done taking picture");
sendBase64ToAPI(path);
```

This is my `sendBase64ToApi` method

```
Future<String> sendBase64ToAPI(String path) async {

  File(path).readAsBytes().then(thenMethod);
  return null;
}

void thenMethod(List bytes){
  print("Start reading file");
  Image image = decodeImage(bytes);

  int x = ((screenWidth/2) + (overlayWidth/2)).toInt();
  int y = ((screenHeight/2) + (overlayHeight/2)).toInt();

  print("Start cropping image");
  image = copyCrop(image, x, y, overlayWidth, overlayHeight);

  var base64Str = base64.encode(image.getBytes());
  print("Done");

  print(base64Str.substring(0,30));
  print(base64Str.substring(base64Str.length-30,base64Str.length-1));
}
```

My UI is completely frozen between 'Start reading file' and 'Start cropping image' although, those are async methods, called without `await` so that shouldn't happen.

Why are those methods not executing asynchronously ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, [this seems to be a known issue](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues/114) from the library I'm using.

The documentation recommends to use the `decodeImage` function in an `Isolate`.

Will keep the question open for a few days, if someone spots what is synchronous in my code.